# Avoid Sitecore Lucene/Solr Indexing of System Folder

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore

I just setup my Solr search functionality in Sitecore and it indexed the site. I can do a search and I get back results. Unfortunately, it indexed TOO much, and is returning system specific things such as templates and analytics nodes in teh content tree. I type in things like 'system' it returns to me things in the /system/ folder and elsewhere.

I was able to reduce a lot of it by adding templates to exclude, but I'd rather just tell it to avoid 1 or two specific folders alltogether (the layout folder, the system folder, etc).

Is there a way to do this in the ContentSearch config? If not, how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom index and restrict it to just the content you want in that index by setting the `root` node:

```xml
<contentSearch>
  <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="my_custom_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        ...
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>web</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
        ....
      </index>
    </indexes>
  </configuration>
</contentSearch>
```

Note that index `id` attribute is set to a custom index name and root node is changed to `root` node. The above was a copy of `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config`, you may need to create a similar one for `master` based on your requirements.

You can find more information about defining your own custom indexes in this blog post: [Defining a custom index in Sitecore 7, the absolute minimum](http://www.mikkelhm.dk/archive/defining-a-custom-index-in-sitecore-7-the-absolute-minimum)

Alternatively, leave the default indexes alone and add a filter to your own search query to restrict the returned results to `/sitecore/content` only.